# Where to start when converting a logical formula to English?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I've got this problem with some atomic sentences, I was just wondering whether when converting it into English I needed to do the brackets first along with precedence or whether I just work my way along left to right.

$$X \implies (X \land Y) \land (Y \lor N) \implies \lnot(Y \implies N)$$

Thank you!

Comment: A paranthesized expression can be treated as a simple sentence. If there are connectives outside the parentheses, they must be dealt with first.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely do the brackets first and go from left to right, however sometimes when you do that the sentence doesn't make sense and you would realize that you might want to go from right to left to make sense of it.